# SQL substring from special character to special character

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column which contain varchar value. I want to take the string part from first space to second space.

Ex: 
DB Value 10/15/2015 10:05:02 AM

Return Value 10:05:02

How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx ?

Comment: what should expected output if it is 10/15/2015 10:05:02 PM ??

Comment: expected output 10:05:02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below for db value `AM`,

```
DECLARE @val AS VARCHAR(100)='10/15/2015 10:05:02 AM'
SELECT @val = CONVERT(TIME ,@val) 
SELECT SUBSTRING(@val ,1 ,8) RetValue
```

[image: Output AM]

Below with db value `PM`,

```
DECLARE @val AS VARCHAR(100)='10/15/2015 10:05:02 PM'
SELECT @val = CONVERT(TIME ,@val) 
SELECT SUBSTRING(@val ,1 ,8) RetVal
```

[image: Output-PM]

If you are using sql-server 2008 and getting below error,

> Type TIME is not a defined system type.

Then try this,

```
DECLARE @val AS VARCHAR(50)='2/15/2015 10:05:02 PM'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR ,CAST(@val AS DATETIME) ,108) ReturnValue
```

[image]

If you have DB value like `'12/15/2015 10:05:02 AM'` OR `'02/15/2015 10:05:02 PM'` and still you want the result in **12 hour** format, you can do something like below,

```
DECLARE @val AS VARCHAR(50)='02/15/2015 10:05:02 PM'
--SET @val = SUBSTRING(@val,1,19)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR ,CAST(SUBSTRING(@val,1,19) AS DATETIME) ,108) ReturnValue
```

'`02/15/2015 10:05:02 PM`' and '`2/15/2015 10:05:02 PM`' - both will return your expected result.

Comment: but for some months @val length will be change . ex. '2/15/2015 10:05:02 PM'. Now substring function will not work correctly

Comment: so what you expect from this value  '2/15/2015 10:05:02 PM' ? -

Comment: expected result 10:05:02

Comment: other issue is when running your query 'Type TIME is not a defined system type.' error comming

Comment: okay. can you just try this by removing last two lines just put this line, SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR ,CAST(@val AS DATETIME) ,108) ReturnValue

Comment: @Tom - please check my updated answer. It will give your expected output in both cases - AM or PM.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @temp nvarchar(50)= cast('10/15/2015 10:05:02 AM' as time)
```

Now, @temp contains time value only.
if you want to remove milliseconds from line, then you can use SUBSTRING function.

```
Select SUBSTRING(@temp,1,8)
```

Comment: I think he has already mentioned that - 'column which contain varchar value` - so no need to take nvarchar and then cast as time. also your answer seems like mine. would be better if you provide some comments on my answer.